# Set same gaps between texts in TextView through xml

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to use `textView` in my app. How do I keep the same gaps between the text in paragraph?

[image]

Comment: try with include "\n" in paragraph.

Comment: <TextView
         android:id="@+id/article_title"
         android:layout_gravity="top"
         android:gravity="left"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="something long paragraph"/>

Comment: Why don't you place a image instead of TextView? Design a image with a necessary alignment and place it in there.its static text only know?

Comment: yup #Sharath its a static text. But i think placing the image is not a good idea. and i found a solution using <WebView> :)

Comment: The  below code posted by Pankaj Nimgade is exactly what i wanted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you might be looking for is **`align-justify`** for the text you are showing...

you can try this out if this is want you want to do

Change `TextView` to `WebView`

Example :

```
  <WebView
  android:id="@+id/text_webView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#FFFFFF"
  android:gravity="start"
  android:textColor="#555555" />



text_webView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_webView);

            String text;
            text = "<html><body>" + "<p align=\"justify\" >";
                text+= "put your text here";
            text+= "</body></html>";
            text_webView.loadData(text, "text/html; charset=UTF-8",null);
```

[image]

**`align-justify`** is a feature of HTML coding and usually used in websites to make the right and left alignment to the paragraph without distorting the text inside it... in another words it maintains the gaps between the words inside the text..

Apparently the `TextView` in android does not support any feature like this to **`align-justify`** the text, but as this can only be applied in Websites we can assume `WebView` which supports HTML coding will handle our requirement.

Comment: thanks buddy i will try it :) @pankaj Nimgade

Comment: @nawinkhatiwada, you are welcome :)

Comment: thank you Pankaj Nimgade it worked perfectly :)\

Comment: great, kindly accept the answer :)

Comment: @PankajNimgade that's a cool thing can you explain me why you used webview instead of textview??

Comment: @Abhishek, I have updated the Answer, should require further explanation let me know :)

Comment: @PankajNimgade thanks a lot for it :)

Comment: @PankajNimgade take a upvote :D